# What happens if we cut a convex lens horizontally?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Does the focal length change? Or does it remain constant and only the brightness of the image is reduced?

[image]

Comment: The shape of the [bokeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh) will change to match the new shape of the lens aperture.  Assuming the lens is cut exactly through the center, the bokeh will become semicircles instead of full circles.

Comment: Is the cut off portion of the lens discarded or displaced like in the picture?

Comment: @MarkH its displaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will end up with 2 lenses at different locations and some light will go to 1 lens, some to the other and some to both resulting in 3 images in 3 different planes - so yes the focal length will change for the 2 new images.

Each lens piece will have a lower aperture than the full lens and therefore a lower image quality.

In microscopy we often hide part of the incident light (see oblique illumination)- which amounts to the same as using a section of the lens- for increasing contrast at the expense of definition.